# VBA Object variable or With block variable not set - RegEx loop

Tags: vba, loops, foreach

I am stuck - I feel I have checked everything multiple times but I need some pair of fresh eyes on this one:

```
Sub shopNumConvert()

    Call settings

    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim ReplaceString As String
    Dim InputString As String
    Dim ShopRange As Range
    'Dim RegEx As New RegExp
    Dim RegEx As RegExp
        
    SearchString = "[^a-z]{2}"
    ReplaceString = "0\\1"
    Set ShopRange = DataWs.Range("G2:G10")
    Set RegEx = New RegExp

    For Each cell In ShopRange
    
        If SearchString <> "" Then
            InputString = cell.Value

            With RegEx
                .Global = True             
                .IgnoreCase = False         
                .MultiLine = True          
                .Pattern = SearchString     
            End With
        
            If RegEx.Test(InputString) Then                                     
                ShopRange.Value = (RegEx.Replace(InputString, ReplaceString))
            End If
        
        End If
    
    Next
    
    Set RegEx = Nothing

End Sub
```

Why do I get the error message **Object variable or With block variable not set**

In settings() I have defined which sheet 'DataWs' is

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the code for `settings()`? Sounds like a problem of scope.

Comment: On which line does the error occur? And just to be on the safe side, I'd add a `If Not cell Is Nothing Then ...` after the `For each...` line. And obviously a closing `End If` at the bottom.

Comment: ShopRange is multiple cells whereas the replace regexp returns a single string so I suspect you have used ShopRange instead of the (badly chosen name) cell.. Also, it is good practise to indicate the line of code which is generating the error.

Comment: @freeflow - `cell` is a perfectly good name though, right? There's no confusion between `cell` and `Cells`? It seems like `DataWs` is the culprit here.

Comment: Cell as a variable name in Excel, which has they Keyword Cells, is bad practise because it introduces too much cognitive load.  myCell would have been much better and not an excessive amount of extra typing.

Comment: Using `cell` is a perfect variable name to use when referencing a single cell within a range of `Cells`. It's clear and concise. `myCell` doesn't add any value **in my opinion**, and can be distracting from the purpose of what the variable is. This all of course is subjective

Comment: `DataWs` is your error point; however, you did not provide code for `Call Settings` to figure out why it's failing. Really you should try to use the worksheets [Codename](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/code-name-sheet1/) and this would prevent from this issue happening. Please provide your `Settings` code for more help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments (and good practice advise - not working with VBA frequently so I am learning on the go)!

The problem was indeed with `DataWs` and I had to change something in `settings()` - the code as posted now runs without throwing an error - I will however look at a few of your comments and see how to incorporate those for improving the code.

Best,
Janine